# How to pass /" as it is to CDT run configuration?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

To add any parameters while running C-Project, we open the configuration and provide arguments under arguments tab.

Now I want to pass the string **\"Hello all\"** as it is.

It is passed as:
**"Hello all"** the '\' is escaped.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the escape characters and the double quotes: `\\\"Hello all\\\"`

Comment: It returns it as: \\"Hello world\\", but I want it as \"Hello world\" . The \\ and \ make a difference for me. Any idea?

Comment: then it seems to be a bug. a possible crap workaround is creating an environment variable containing the string and passing it as parameter. try it and open a bug [here](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced&classification=Tools&product=CDT&component=cdt-debug&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED).

Comment: Ya it did!! Well I did a few tweaks with my program and this worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Well its pretty much nothing actually!! I was expecting in my program to get exactly one \ but I changed to to start with \ or \\ and then have a string that I need and end with \ or \\. In CDT I passed it as you said.

Comment: Still I have a feeling I am doing something wrong! I will go through it again and I will update if I had done any other mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Program arguments** edit box, enter `"\\\"Hello all\\\""`. Works for me in Eclipse 3.8.1